# How to create a MySql innodb Cluster

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, nodes, innodb

I am trying some days now to create a cluster with some nodes using the innodb database in MySQL but I can't find any documentation how to do so. Does anyone has a clue about it ?

Comment: use MariaDB Galera Cluster. For a Production System you must have 3 Nodes see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/what-is-mariadb-galera-cluster/

Comment: @BerndBuffen thanks a lot , i will check it

Comment: if you have more questions about galera, you can send me a e-mail

Comment: Or, did you mean something else by "MySQL innodb Cluster"?  There is "NDB Cluster" and others.